# Linq query to traverse tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Schema has changed under me so that users FK is no longer in the entries table, but is indirectly referenced via the accounts table

I have the following tables:
Users
Accounts (FK from Users)
Entries (FK from Accounts)

I basically want to get the Entries for a particular user using LINQ from:

```
var userAccounts = context.User.Include("Accounts").Include("Entries").Where(s => s.UserId == userId);
```

This was the previous query before the User was removed from Entries:

```
return (from pc in userAccounts
    select new Entry{
         Timestamp = pc.Timestamp,
         Log = pc.Log }).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

Just unsure how to traverse the tables and populate the Entry type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer an association based approach rather than joins, consider the following:

```
var userAccounts = from user in context.User
                   where user.UserId == userId
                   from account in user.Accounts
                   from entry in account.Entries
                   select entry;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can join user accounts table with entries so you can get all entries with userId.

something like that :

```
from ua in userAccounts join en in entries on ua.accountId equals en.accountId  into data
where data.userId = someId 
select data.entries
```

hope this helps.